# SQL find a sequence count for a sport

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm searching for a SELECT that will gives me a "sequence count". Take a sport of your choice and I want to know how many games a player is having a goal (hockey, soccer) or a hit (baseball) for example.

So I have this table DaysData

```
INSERT @DaysData(PlayerID, GameDate, GoalsInGame)
VALUES
(100, '20180105', 0),
(100, '20180107', 1),
(100, '20180109', 1),
(100, '20180111', 2),
(100, '20180113', 1),
(100, '20180115', 0),
(100, '20180117', 0),
(100, '20180118', 1),
(100, '20180120', 1),
(100, '20180122', 3),
(100, '20180124', 2),
(100, '20180125', 1),
(100, '20180127', 0),
(100, '20180129', 0),
(100, '20180130', 1);
```

So I want to have something telling me: Player 100

- has a sequence of 4 games with a goal between 20180107 and 20180113 (making 5 goals during this streak)
- and a sequence of 5 games with a goal between 20180118 and 20180125  (making 8 goals during this streak)
- and finally a sequence of 1 game with a goal between 20180130 and 20180130

```
    CountGameSequence , DateFrom ,  DateTo 
    4 ,                 20180107 , 20180113 
    5 ,                 20180118 , 20180125
    1 ,                 20180130 , 20180130
```

I try many things with LEAD, LAG , RowNumber(), etc...I never find a way to get the good query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  In your case, I think a difference of row numbers works well:

```
select playerid, min(gamedate), max(gamedate), count(*) as sequence_length
from (select dd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by playerid order by gamedate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by playerid, sign(goalsingame) order by gamedate) as seqnum_2
      from @DaysData dd
     ) dd
where goalsingame > 0
group by playerid, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by sequence_length desc;
```

The one trick to this is using `sign()` to capture games where the player has a score.  That is a convenience.  The code `(case when goalsingame > 0 then 1 else 0 end)` would do the same thing.

Why does this work?  That is a bit hard to explain.  However, I find that if you look at the results from the subquery you will quickly see how the difference in the two sequence numbers identifies adjacent values.

Comment: Exactly,THANKS! In my query I replace the @DaysData by my table and linked table : from DaysData inner Join Calendar on XX = yy  And I get what I want. Genius :)